# Calculate Mean Values in 2D Array Using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two 2D arrays with similar size of 67x30831. I was wondering how do I average the rows in order to have only one 2D array with size 67x30831 using numpy. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `(arr1+arr2)/2`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to average the 2 arrays, @Quang Hoang's answer would be right:

```
mean = (arr1 + arr2) / 2.
```

If you want to average across rows, use `np.mean(arr1, axis=1)`, `axis=1` to compute across columns, so you have 67 means.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it.